# Admob Ads with Firebase Integration Issue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, admob

I recently added Firebase to my Swift project. I followed their steps exactly and ran into trouble including Admob 'GoogleMobileAds'. I installed the Firebase pod using CocoaPods (pod 'Firebase').

The part Im confused about is that in there setup [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#add_the_sdk)  they say the install of pod 'Firebase' links to all the different Firebase features, IE Analytics, AdMob, Realtime Database, etc (if I am reading that right). After installing just the pod 'Firebase', Firebase installs fine in App but when adding an AdMob Ad I cant seem to find or import the module 'GoogleMobileAds'. Do I have to install each pod separately? Like Firebase/Core, Firebase/Admob, etc. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Podfile**:

```
platform:ios, '9.0'

target 'MyApp' do

use_frameworks!

pod 'Firebase'

end
```

Comment: update question with your pod file content.

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start#streamlined_using_cocoapods) your pod file need to have these to integrate Admob

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
```

Comment: Yea, I read that Documentation as well. I thought based on [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#add_the_sdk) documentation that installing that top-level pod that all subspecs are included with it. For instance if I want to have Admobs and later use Real-time Database, I thought the top-level includes everything but Im guessing the wording in the documentation only includes /Core.

Comment: do you have all of the pods file like messaging and admob installed with `Firebase` pod ?

Comment: When I installed pod 'Firebase', The following dependencies were installed. Firebase (3.2.1), FirebaseAnalytics (3.2.0), FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.6), GoogleInterchangeUtilities, GoogleSymbolUtilities, and GoogleUtilities.

Comment: does not seem to have Admob one . i  will suggest to just follow along the doc i referred and use the admob pod explicitly